# Using an iso to create a VMware vmdk

Tags: vmware-server, iso

Can anyone point me to some documentation about how I can use an Iso to create a Vmware environment.

For instance, there's this guy who made his own version of Ubuntu, with loads of extra programs added. Before I try this, I'm gonna test it using vmware server. But I'm kinda confused as to how to do this with only the ISO file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just create a new VM and attach the ISO into the virtual CD-ROM drive. You can do this when you create the VM. When you boot it, you will be able to install it as if you were doing it on a real machine.

Comment: Yeah, this is our preferred way to do it since we just have bucketloads on install ISOs (all properly licensed of course) and they install into VMs a lot faster than the real media.